# Is there a way in Javascript/Typescript to take an array of strings that are key1,value1,key2,value2... And make them result to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, redis

From Redis the raw output is a bunch of nested arrays. Fun!

Just to be clear the output array is NOT `[{key:value}, {key:value}]`
But rather `['key1','value1','key2','value2','key3','value3']`

The solution I have come up with is the following. It doesn't seem like this is the most performant or rational solution to do for every stream key message coming through. First, I sperate out the array to keys and values and then put them back together in a final object.

```js
const dataArray = messages[0][1];
const arrayHelper = async (value: any, key: any): Promise<object> => {
  const keys = await value.filter((key: string, index: number) => {
     return index % 2 === 0
   });
   const values = await value.filter((key: string, index: number) => {
     return index % 2 === 1
   });
   const data = Object.fromEntries(await keys.map((_: string, i: string) => [keys[i], values[i]]));
   return data;
}
```

Here is final Object:

```json
{
 id: 'smithfamily:1234598',
 from: 'smithfamily:1234598',
 time_stamp: '1665252087761',
 username: 'test',
 event: 'connected',
 connected_at: '1665252087761',
 start: 'true'
}
```

Is this performant? Is there a better way to do this? I've tried many different things but couldn't get the pair to match correctly like the above method.

Comment: what's the point of these `await`s?

Comment: to me await is a blocking operation that makes they 'await' until the operation is done. In javascript await is like a blocking operation on the thread. I think your point is the operations are in synchronous so what's the point. yea I get that.

Comment: It's only useful if the value is a _promise_ - the filter method just returns an array, nothing asynchronous is happening so it would be blocking anyway.

Comment: agreed. It's a bad practice.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for that explanation. In javascript when you call async/await does that mean it is a blocking operation until next. If not, like other typed languages i.e. .net, you have to explicitly create a parallel operation. How do you that in JS. Meaning I want all of my asyncs happening in parallel.

Comment: so @gog my thought is if you could make the keys and values go in parallel that would make the operation that much faster.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew: not in javascript. There are no means in js to create threads or parallel processes.

Comment: doesn't that really hamper the idea of promises or better yet async/await? They're good for the blocking part because it's almost as if the synchronous operation for a running "promise"/operation i.e. rest call is more like the parallel part (in a bad way.) But I guess on a single thread that just wouldn't be possible. Thanks. Javascript with threads. The next big thing!!! lol

Answer (score 4):

I'd do that in a simple old school way:

```js
function toObj(a) {
    let obj = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2)
        obj[a[i]] = a[i + 1]
    return obj
}


console.log(
    toObj(
        ['key1','value1','key2','value2','key3','value3']
    )
)
```